# Use ReplacePart from an element n to an element m of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to replace a part of a list from  an element n to an  element m by zeros.
I believe the function ReplacePart could be useful

Example: I want to replace elements from 2 to 4 by zeros :

**INPUT :** {1,2,3,4,5}

**OUTPUT :** {1,0,0,0,5}

Comment: If your input is called `l1` then `l1[[2;;4]]=0` will modify the list as you wish. Is that the answer you want?

Comment: Yes thank you, I didn't expected that to be that simple .

Comment: Be aware that the solution offered by @HighPerformanceMark will change the value of `l1`, but `ReplacePart[l1, Transpose@{Range[2, 4]} -> 0]` will not.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
lst = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
ReplacePart[lst, Range[2, 4] /. x_?NumberQ -> Rule[x, 0]]

(*   {1, 0, 0, 0, 5}   *)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 4):

```
alist = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
ReplacePart[alist, (i_ /; 1 < i < 5) -> 0]
```

> {1, 0, 0, 0, 5}

or

```
   alist = ReplacePart[alist, (i_ /; 1 < i < 5) -> 0]
```

if you want to modify `alist` itself.

Answer (score 4):

```
MapAt[0 &, lst, 2;;4]

(* {1, 0, 0, 0, 5} *)
```

**Original Answer**

```
SubsetMap[0 #&, lst, Range[2,4]]
(* {1, 0, 0, 0, 5} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that continuous values need to be filtered.

```
alist = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
alist /. x_ /; x >= 2 && x <= 4 -> 0
```

> {1, 0, 0, 0, 5}

If you want to filter just integers, consider the following.

```
blist = {1, 2, 2.2, 3, 3.2, 4, 4.4, 5, 6}

blist /. x_Integer /; x >= 2 && x <= 4 -> 0
```

> {1, 0, 2.2, 0, 3.2, 0, 4.4, 5, 6}

-------------- Apply the continuous version on blist

```
blist /. x_ /; x >= 2 && x <= 4 -> 0

{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.4, 5, 6}
```

------------- or is it list elements at index 2 through to 4 that you need to zero out?

```
ReplacePart[alist, {{2}, {3}, {4}} -> 0]
```

> {1, 0, 0, 0, 5}

Answer (score 2):

I would like to promote `ReplaceAt` which came with `V 13.1`.

It uses the same position syntax as `MapAt`, allowing `Span`s

```
ReplaceAt[Range[5], _ :> 0, 2 ;; 4]
```

{1, 0, 0, 0, 5}

as well as lists like those returned by `Position`:

```
ReplaceAt[Range[5], _ :> 0, List /@ Range[2, 4]
```

{1, 0, 0, 0, 5}

The advantage of `ReplaceAt` over `MapAt` is that we can inject selection criteria like `Syed` did in his second example:

```
blist = {1, 2, 2.2, 3, 3.2, 4, 4.4, 5, 6};

ReplaceAt[blist, _Integer :> 0, 2 ;; 4]
```

{1, 0, 2.2, 0, 3.2, 4, 4.4, 5, 6}

In this simple example the `ReplaceAt` syntax is easier to read (for me) than the `ReplaceAll` and `ReplacePart` formulas.

Comment: (+1) I also like the use of `ReplaceAt`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `MapThread`:

```
MapThread[If[Or @@ Thread[#2 == Drop[list, {2, 4}]], #1, 0] &, {list, list}]

(*{1, 0, 0, 0, 5}*)
```